# linear-gradient not working in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, linear-gradients

After a good amount of search I am stuck with linear-gradient which works in Firefox but not in Chrome.

I added `-webkit-` before linear-gradient as described in one reference but still not working I think the problem is in gradient axis

My code

```
<nav class="top_menu">
    <ul class="black_high">
        <li class="first active"> <a href="#">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">news</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

```css
.top_menu ul li.active a::after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    transform:none;

    content: '';
    opacity: 1;
    background: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(left, transparent 0%,#fff 50%,transparent 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, transparent 0%,#fff 50%,transparent 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left, transparent 0%,#fff 50%,transparent 100%);
}
```

Creates a fiddle here -- http://jsfiddle.net/h2zu5xx2/4/

Any hint/suggestion will do great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your css for your webkit gradient is wrong. Invalid propperty if you look at it, so the syntax is wrong. Have you looked at it from out of an inspector such as the dev tool in chrome, you could have easy spotted it.

Comment: @Hashem I couldn't comment in your answer also can't see it any more. But I want to say thank you so much for pointing my mistakes and this brilliant explanation.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First of all note that `-webkit-gradient` was intended by Apple and implemented in 2008 in Webkit based web browsers (for instance Safari 4) which has a pretty different syntax than the W3C standard:

```
-webkit-gradient(<type>, <point> [, <radius>]?, <point> [, <radius>]? [, <stop>]*)
```

For instance:

```css
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#87e0fd), color-stop(40%,#53cbf1), color-stop(100%,#05abe0));
```

This is why you couldn't get it to work in your case.

A year later Mozilla introduced `-moz-linear-gradient` (since Firefox 3.6) which has also a different syntax than the old Webkit version but then it implemented in Webkit under `-webkit-linear-gradient`:

```
-moz-linear-gradient([ [ [top | bottom] || [left | right] ],]? <color-stop>[, <color-stop>]+)
```

However the W3C standard version of `linear-gradient` is quiet different, the formal syntax of [`linear-gradient()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images-3/#linear-gradients) expression is:

```
linear-gradient() = linear-gradient(
  [ <angle> | to <side-or-corner> ]? ,
  <color-stop-list>
)
<side-or-corner> = [left | right] || [top | bottom]
```

As can be seen in your posted code, the other mistake is the lack of `to <side>` in the W3C version. Therefore, in your case it should be:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/h2zu5xx2/6/)**.

```css
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, transparent), color-stop(50%,#fff), color-stop(100%,transparent)); /* Chrome, Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, transparent 0%,#fff 50%,transparent 100%); /* Chrome10+, Safari5.1+ */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, transparent 0%,#fff 50%,transparent 100%);    /* FF3.6+ */
background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 0%,#fff 50%,transparent 100%);      /* W3C */
```

Comment: This answer is key to any css gradient work.   linear-gradient needs different treatment for each browser.  Consider using a generator, such as https://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, transparent 0%,#fff 50%,transparent 100%);
```

as the similar definition to Mozilla's.

Answer (score -1):

```
background: rgb(0,0,0);
background: linear-gradient(NaNdeg, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%);
```

This is the answer, check it !!!
(Note* - NaN is as same as 'xx' means you can change the value as per as need required.)

Or another way is that you can create gradients using Gradient generator.
Link to my self-made gradient-generator:- https://dynamicmortal.github.io/GradientGenerator/

(Simply just copy the css generated)

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: NaN is just a way to tell 'xx' means you can fill yourself the answer as per needed.