# Gradient effect on a text via css does not work with FF

Tags: css, gradient

I have a problem with FF and a gradient applied to a text.

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t26mr59r/) with this CSS:

```
rainbow{
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #4d2dac), color-stop(0.03, #542ea8), color-stop(0.06, #5b2fa0), color-stop(0.09, #64319a), color-stop(0.12, #6d3193), color-stop(0.15, #75338c), color-stop(0.18, #7f3486), color-stop(0.21, #8b357e), color-stop(0.24, #933776), color-stop(0.27, #9f386e), color-stop(0.30, #ab3a65), color-stop(0.33, #b63e61), color-stop(0.36, #bd476a), color-stop(0.39, #c25074), color-stop(0.42, #c8587c), color-stop(0.45, #d06287), color-stop(0.48, #d86b92), color-stop(0.51, #dd7492), color-stop(0.54, #e17f80), color-stop(0.57, #e58b6d), color-stop(0.60, #eb955c), color-stop(0.63, #ef9e4c), color-stop(0.66, #eca348), color-stop(0.69, #e7a547), color-stop(0.72, #e3a946), color-stop(0.75, #dfab46), color-stop(0.78, #daae45), color-stop(0.81, #d6b244), color-stop(0.84, #d2b442), color-stop(0.87, #cdb841), color-stop(0.90, #c7bb41), color-stop(0.93, #c3be40), color-stop(0.96, #bfc241), color-stop(1, #bcc33e));
  background-image: -moz-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #4d2dac), color-stop(0.03, #542ea8), color-stop(0.06, #5b2fa0), color-stop(0.09, #64319a), color-stop(0.12, #6d3193), color-stop(0.15, #75338c), color-stop(0.18, #7f3486), color-stop(0.21, #8b357e), color-stop(0.24, #933776), color-stop(0.27, #9f386e), color-stop(0.30, #ab3a65), color-stop(0.33, #b63e61), color-stop(0.36, #bd476a), color-stop(0.39, #c25074), color-stop(0.42, #c8587c), color-stop(0.45, #d06287), color-stop(0.48, #d86b92), color-stop(0.51, #dd7492), color-stop(0.54, #e17f80), color-stop(0.57, #e58b6d), color-stop(0.60, #eb955c), color-stop(0.63, #ef9e4c), color-stop(0.66, #eca348), color-stop(0.69, #e7a547), color-stop(0.72, #e3a946), color-stop(0.75, #dfab46), color-stop(0.78, #daae45), color-stop(0.81, #d6b244), color-stop(0.84, #d2b442), color-stop(0.87, #cdb841), color-stop(0.90, #c7bb41), color-stop(0.93, #c3be40), color-stop(0.96, #bfc241), color-stop(1, #bcc33e));
  background-image: -ms-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #4d2dac), color-stop(0.03, #542ea8), color-stop(0.06, #5b2fa0), color-stop(0.09, #64319a), color-stop(0.12, #6d3193), color-stop(0.15, #75338c), color-stop(0.18, #7f3486), color-stop(0.21, #8b357e), color-stop(0.24, #933776), color-stop(0.27, #9f386e), color-stop(0.30, #ab3a65), color-stop(0.33, #b63e61), color-stop(0.36, #bd476a), color-stop(0.39, #c25074), color-stop(0.42, #c8587c), color-stop(0.45, #d06287), color-stop(0.48, #d86b92), color-stop(0.51, #dd7492), color-stop(0.54, #e17f80), color-stop(0.57, #e58b6d), color-stop(0.60, #eb955c), color-stop(0.63, #ef9e4c), color-stop(0.66, #eca348), color-stop(0.69, #e7a547), color-stop(0.72, #e3a946), color-stop(0.75, #dfab46), color-stop(0.78, #daae45), color-stop(0.81, #d6b244), color-stop(0.84, #d2b442), color-stop(0.87, #cdb841), color-stop(0.90, #c7bb41), color-stop(0.93, #c3be40), color-stop(0.96, #bfc241), color-stop(1, #bcc33e));
  background-image: gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #4d2dac), color-stop(0.03, #542ea8), color-stop(0.06, #5b2fa0), color-stop(0.09, #64319a), color-stop(0.12, #6d3193), color-stop(0.15, #75338c), color-stop(0.18, #7f3486), color-stop(0.21, #8b357e), color-stop(0.24, #933776), color-stop(0.27, #9f386e), color-stop(0.30, #ab3a65), color-stop(0.33, #b63e61), color-stop(0.36, #bd476a), color-stop(0.39, #c25074), color-stop(0.42, #c8587c), color-stop(0.45, #d06287), color-stop(0.48, #d86b92), color-stop(0.51, #dd7492), color-stop(0.54, #e17f80), color-stop(0.57, #e58b6d), color-stop(0.60, #eb955c), color-stop(0.63, #ef9e4c), color-stop(0.66, #eca348), color-stop(0.69, #e7a547), color-stop(0.72, #e3a946), color-stop(0.75, #dfab46), color-stop(0.78, #daae45), color-stop(0.81, #d6b244), color-stop(0.84, #d2b442), color-stop(0.87, #cdb841), color-stop(0.90, #c7bb41), color-stop(0.93, #c3be40), color-stop(0.96, #bfc241), color-stop(1, #bcc33e));
  color:transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

It works under Safari, Chrome and I think under IE, but it does not work under FF. 
If you run the jsfiddle under FF you see a blank html result, but the text is present, only not visible.

Under Android it does not work too, but with a different problem (a long gradient box).

If there is an jquery/angularjs plugin that use svg when gradient is not applicable I can use it.

And I have an image that I can use for the gradient background.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26318988/linear-gradient-not-working-in-chrome/26319056#26319056

Comment: There was never such `-moz-gradient()` notation, nor `-ms-gradient()` / `gradient()`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fix the whole thing but the syntax for the -moz gradient is a little different.  Should be something more like:

```css
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #4d2dac 0, #542ea8 25%, #5b2fa0 50%);
```

...etc.

Comment: Hi, it does not work. I have update the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t26mr59r/2/ . The result is a problem like the Android version